# CSS div and dot div

Tags: html, css

```
.div1 {

}

div.div1 {

}
```

What's the difference between the codes above? I want to use `<div class = "div1"></div>` in my code and as I searched it both ways seems to work... Which one should I use? Ty

Comment: `.` is a class selector(Selects all elements with the class name div1) `div` is a tag selector. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/611/selectors#t=201703031503567057781

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.div1` defines css for all the elements having class `div1`.But `div.div1`  defines the css for the `div` elements having class `div1`.

**See the small example.** for  `div.div1` just class `div1` is not `sufficient` it also have the `div` element.

```css
.div1{
  color:red;
}
div.div1{
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<p class="div1">
P with class div1
</p>
<div class="div1">
Div with class div1
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

`.div1` selects **all** elements with the class `div1` while `div.div1` only selects div elements with the class `div1`

*"Which one should I use?"* That depends on how your page is structured and whether you have any other elements other than divs with the class `div1`